# Extract DLL from Jar

Tags: java, io

I have a project set up with a resources directory similar to this:

```
[Project]
    [java]
        MainClass
        ...
        ...
    [resources]
        MyDll.dll
```

I want to be able to load `MyDll.dll` using `System.load()`. I read that to be able to do this from the jar, I need to first extract the dll to a temporary location. I am currently using this code to do so:

```
try {
    InputStream input = this.class.getResourceAsStream("MyDll.dll");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read = -1;
    File temp = File.createTempFile("MyDll.dll", "");
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(temp);

    while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    output.close();
    input.close();

    System.load(temp.getAbsolutePath());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, I think it's not finding the file. `input` is always `null`. Is there a way I can locate `MyDll.dll` in the resources folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
    InputStream input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MyDll.dll");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. It still returns null.

Comment: @grandmind1 try with classloader, and you are sure that the file exists ? )

Comment: Code only answers are usually not helpful. Add some explanation.